# How to have an optional primary key with DynamoDB?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I have a relationship whereby each SITE can have one or more CAMERAs.

So the parent-child relatioship would be that of SITE->CAMERA[s].

The 99% of my queries will be "Give me all the cameras at a given site" and "Give me camera XYZ" and "Give me all cameras where enabled===true" -- at roughly 1:1:1 ratio.

The DynamoDB design, if I understand correctly, would be to have the partition key be 'SITE_ID' and the sort key be 'CAMERA_ID'.  Done and done.

....

**However**, not every CAMERA belongs to a SITE.  About 10% of my CAMERAs are not associated with a SITE.   I *could* just put 'noSite' or something as the Partitionkey, but that seems like a kludge... or is it?

I'm new to DynamoDB and unsure how best to set up this relationship. I've always just used MongoDB  and never spent time in the SQL world, so needing to worry about indexes isn't something I have experience with.   Cost is more important than raw speed and the DB will remain somewhat small (currently around 500 cameras and likely never more than 10k).

What is the best way to set up this table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Detailed question first:  a `noSite` key is not a bad design choice for unassigned cameras.  `SiteID` is important and
the key cannot be blank.

Your access patterns give you flexibility. Your low data volumes reduce the stakes of the design decisions.

**What are the `Partion Key` and `Sort Key` names?**  Regardless of which "columns" you end up selecting for the keys, naming the keys `PK` and `SK` give you the option to add other record types in a [single-table design](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-modeling-nosql-B.html) later.  This is a common practice.

**What are the `PK` and `SK` columns?**

You have two good options for PK and SK for your Camera records:

```sh
# Option 1 - marginally better, CameraID has the higher cardinality
PK: CameraID, SK: SiteID  

# Option 2
PK: SiteID, SK: CameraID
```

At this point, 1 of your "queries" will be executed as a `query` (faster and cheaper) and the other 2 as `scans` (slower and more expensive).  Scanning 500 records is nothing, though, so you could be "done and done" as you say.

**Sooner, Later or Never**

If required, we can remove the `scan` operations by adding [secondary indexes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GSI.html).  Secondary indexes add storage cost (records are literally duplicated) but reduce access costs. Net net change is case dependent.  Performance will improve.

```sh
# Add an index to query "Give me all the cameras at a given site" 
GSI1PK: SiteID, GSI1SK: CameraID # reverse your choice for primary keys

# or, to get fancy and be able to query enabled cameras by site, too, use a concatenated SK with a begins_with query
GSI1PK: SiteID, GSI1SK: Enabled#True#CameraID
```

```sh
# Add an index to query "Give me all cameras where enabled===true"
# Concatenate SiteID and CameraID in the GSI Sort Key to enable 2 types of queries
#  1. all enabled cameras?  GSI2PK = true and GSI2SK > "" 
#  2. all enabled cameras at Site123?  GSI2PK = true and GSI2SK begins_with("Site123")
GSI2PK: Enabled, GSI2SK:  SiteID#CameraID
```

Comment: GSI can be added at a later time, right?   Concatenating is an interesting idea as well.  Thank you!

Comment: It seems that if I have the cameraID as the PK, there is no point in having the siteID be a SK because there will never be multiple matching PKs... (and if I ever wanted to increase speeds on SiteID searchings, I'd make a GSI anyway)...  do I understand correctly?

Comment: Glad to help!  Right, Global indexes can be added later.  And also right about the SiteID SK not doing work for you in Camera records - with a big if - if Cameras never change sites (or switch from `noSite` to a site).  If cameras can move, you may later choose to make use of the SiteID in the SK to implement a [versioning pattern](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/implementing-version-control-using-amazon-dynamodb/).